# How to compare java object in jess

Tags: jess

I have a problem when I compare java object as attribute inside the java class

This is my clp file

```
(import Model.*)

(deftemplate PizzaBase    
    (declare (from-class PizzaBase)  
             (include-variables TRUE)))  

(deftemplate PizzaTopping   
    (declare (from-class PizzaTopping)  
             (include-variables TRUE)))  

(deftemplate Pizza   
    (declare (from-class Pizza)  
             (include-variables TRUE)))  

(defrule make-pizza
        ?pizzaBase1 <-(PizzaBase{size == 9})
        (Pizza(pizzaBase ?pizzaBase1))  
        =>  
         (add (new PizzaBase "New DeepPan" 10))  
         )
```

According from my rule, I want to create a new pizzaBase.When the pizzaBase object in Pizza equal pizzaBase1(size = 9), but JESS is not create a new fact for me.
From my thinking, I think JESS cannot compare the Java object that create from the class.Therefore, There isn't add any fact to JESS.

So,"How to solve this problem?",because I look on the manual on the JESS website but there aren't any title that according my problem.

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have overlooked section 5.3.2., Adding Java objects to working memory.

A Java object isn't the same as a fact, even when you derive a shadow (!) fact from a POJO, using from-class and include-variables. A fact *contains* a reference to the Java object you insert by calling `(add ?aNewObject)` in the reserved slot name `OBJECT`.

Change your rule like this:

```
 (defrule make-pizza
    (PizzaBase{size == 9}(OBJECT ?pizzaBase1))
    (Pizza(pizzaBase ?pizzaBase1))  
    =>  
     (add (new PizzaBase "New DeepPan" 10))  
     )
```

Comment: Thank a lot !!! It work right now.May I ask you a question?.This solution can work with the list of java Object or not ?

Comment: You should show some code where people can see which "list" you mean, in which Java class it occurs and what should match what. - It's probably best to mark this question as "answered" and start a new question, posting all the details.